# If $(a^2−b^2)$ is a prime number where $a$ and $b\in N$, then:

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $(a^2−b^2)$ is a prime number where $a$ and $b\in N$, then:

1. $a^2−b^2 = 3$
2. $a^2−b^2 = a−b$
3. $a^2−b^2 = a+b$
4. $a^2−b^2 = 5$

---

My attempt:

$(a^2-b^2)=(a-b)(a+b)$

if $a + b = 1$ and $a^2 + b^2$ is prime. (Since 
$\cfrac{a^4 − b^4}{a- b}
 = (a + b)(a^2 + b^2)$.

Thus, in this case the pair $(a, b)$ must be $(x + 1, −x)$ and $x^2 + (x + 1)^2$ must be prime. That is, $x$ must be in [OEIS A027861](https://oeis.org/A027861).)

I didn't find proper proof.

> Can you explain it, please?

Comment: What *is* your question?

Comment: @Starfall, why voted down?

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted...

Comment: Downvoters, please lease reason for voted down too.

Comment: @Starfall, I think you can feel, if you voted down without proper reason? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899159/is-the-difference-of-two-irrationals-which-are-each-contained-under-a-single-squ/1899216#comment3896542_1899216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a^2-b^2$ is prime, either $a=1-b$ or $a=b+1$. Note that $a-b < a+b$, so $a+b = 1 \implies a-b<1$ is a contradiction, hence $a-b=1$, hence $a^2-b^2 = a+b$.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If $a^2-b^2$ is a prime number, then $a-b$ must be $1$, because for any $a,b\in N$, $a+b\ne 1$. This directly leads to the result that $a^2-b^2=a+b$.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: Happy to help:)